# Update wp_postmeta table based on 2 keys

Tags: functions, database, post-meta

I want to update the wp_postmeta table in the database based on 2 keys, is there a way to do that using any of the wordpress default functions. This is my DB query which is working fine:

```
$sql = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value + 1 WHERE post_id = 167788 AND meta_key = \"tie_views\"";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.

These are some WP functions to get, add and update post meta values:

[get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

[add_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/)

[update_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

Your code could be:

```
$meta_value = (int) get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_key', true );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_key', $meta_value + 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested it, it is working fine. Please be kind enough to tell me what does the first (int) means

Comment: @H_alt That's because the function returns a single string value, if you want to use it as a number you should cast the value to proper type.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I forgot about the type casting, you are right.